# How to "git pull" leaving unfinished branch

Tags: git, branch, git-pull, pull, merge-conflict-resolution

I created "branch A" and was working on it. I sent a pull request to the main branch, however, my pull request was not able to merge into the main as my code has to be modified a bit more. It's left as a draft, waiting for fixes/ commit.

Now, I wanted to switch to the main branch and work on different issues and come back to "branch A" later. I switched to the main then

```
git pull
```

However, I received

```
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
```

Is there any way that I can just leave my current work on "branch A", and work on the main and go back to "branch A" later? Do I set "branch A" as remote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, um, not very short.

What you're calling an "unfinished branch" is not an unfinished *branch*.  Well, Git doesn't define "finished" or "unfinished" at all with respect to branches, so perhaps you can just make up whatever terminology you like here, but [if you do that, you won't really be communicating with anyone](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/789880-i-don-t-know-what-you-mean-by-glory-alice-said).  But when you mention the exact error message you're getting from Git, we can tell what the problem is:

> ```
> error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
> hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
> hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
> ```

What this means is that Git's *index* is in an *unmerged state*.  Unfortunately, in this state, there are only two things you are allowed to do:

- finish the merge (or cherry-pick or revert: whatever caused the conflict), or
- abort the merge (or cherry-pick, etc.) entirely.

This means you can't even leave the current branch!  Your options are to finish the merge-or-whatever-it-is (and then commit the result, as the hint says), or abort the in-progress operation (which erases all your resolutions-so-far).  It's not really very satisfactory, but that's all there is in Git.

Except ... well, there are two ways to work around this.  Git's index is tied to your working tree.

- In Git version 2.5, Git added a new set of commands that all begin with `git worktree`.  These commands allow you to create *new* work-trees (`git worktree add`) that go with the repository you're in.  Each added work-tree gets its own separate index, and its own separate `HEAD` (and other separate items for things Git uses internally, such as the refs Git uses for `git bisect` for instance).

  Now, there are some bugs in `git worktree`.  There's one particularly nasty one that wasn't fixed until Git 2.15.  So if you have one of these older versions of Git, I don't particularly recommend using `git worktree`.  If you do decide to use it with one of these suspect versions of Git, try to get everything done within two weeks (or whatever you have tuned your object prune time to, if you have done that).  But if you have Git 2.15 or later, or can be sure you can finish everything up in a week, you can use `git worktree add` to add a new work-tree, which will be on some other branch—that's a basic requirement of added work-trees—and because the new work-tree has its own index, the fact that the *main* index for the *main* work-tree is busy with this conflict resolution is no longer a problem.
- Your other option, of course, is to just make another clone.

  Each clone comes with a full repository, an index, and a work-tree.  The new clone will be totally independent of the existing clone, so you can do anything you like in the two clones.  There aren't even any constraints about being on different branch names.

As to this:

> Do I set "branch A" as remote?

This question doesn't make any sense, and makes me worry that whichever of these two options you use, you should be reading some basic Git tutorials.

Note that `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*.  That second Git command defaults to `git merge` if you have not set up anything else for it.  I'm guessing you ran a `git pull` earlier, and got stuck in the merge phase, but that's just a guess.